# Chef throws an ArgumentError asking for a name relating to a template resource

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to use [this github cookbook](https://github.com/realityforge/chef-kibana) to install kibana. When I try to run it using the following command, I get this error which does not make much sense to me at this point. What name is the error referring to? According to their docs, all I had to do was run `kibana::default` and that should have done it.

`chef-client -o 'recipe[kibana::default]'`

```
Starting Chef Client, version 12.15.19
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["kibana::default"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - kibana (0.2.1)
  - build-essential (2.3.1)
  - ark (2.2.1)
  - apt (2.8.0)
Installing Cookbook Gems:
Compiling Cookbooks...

================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/kibana/recipes/default.rb
================================================================================

ArgumentError
-------------
You must supply a name when declaring a template resource

Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/kibana/recipes/_service.rb:3:in `from_file'
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/kibana/recipes/kibana5.rb:35:in `from_file'
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/kibana/recipes/default.rb:27:in `from_file'

Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/kibana/recipes/_service.rb:

  1:  # Encoding: utf-8
  2:
  3>> template node['kibana']['service']['template_file'] do
  4:    cookbook node['kibana']['service']['cookbook']
  5:    source node['kibana']['service']['source']
  6:    mode '0o0755'
  7:    variables(
  8:      version: node['kibana']['version'],
  9:      bin_path: node['kibana']['service']['bin_path'],
 10:      options: node['kibana']['service']['options'],
 11:      recent_upstart: (node['platform_family'] != 'rhel')
 12:    )

Platform:
---------
x86_64-linux


Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 03 seconds
```

Comment: What OS are you on? It looks like you would get that error on an unsupported platform.

Comment: What value is in `node['kibana']['service']['template_file']`? I got that error today when my value was nil, so it was basically equivalent to `template nil do`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In chef when you define a resource, you have to give it a name it can be referenced by

In this example:

```
template 'my_template' do
  source 'my_template.erb'
  path '/etc/my_template'
end
```

i'm creating a template and giving it the name **'my_template'**. Very often the name will be used as what would be considered the primary component of the resource, in this case it is the `path`, so it is quite common to see the target file used as the name for a template such as

```
template '/etc/myapp.conf' do
  source 'myapp.conf.erb'
end
```

In this case both the `name` and the `path` are **'/etc/myapp.conf'**

Looking at the attributes file in the cookbook you are referencing there is no default value for the `node['kibana']['service']['template_file']` attribute, and a case statement to populate it, and other information based on the platform and version detected at run time.

So if you are running on a platform that it does not support, the value ends up being empty *(`nil` in ruby)* which is not an acceptable value for a name on a resource

**Relevant section of the attribute file in [github](https://github.com/realityforge/chef-kibana/blob/master/attributes/default.rb) at the time this was written:**

```
# kibana service configurations - defaults to settings for Ubuntu 14.04
case node['platform']
when 'centos', 'amazon'
  if node['platform_version'] < '6.9'
    default['kibana']['service']['provider'] = Chef::Provider::Service::Init::Redhat
    default['kibana']['service']['source'] = 'initd.kibana.erb'
    default['kibana']['service']['template_file'] = '/etc/init.d/kibana'
  else
    default['kibana']['service']['provider'] = Chef::Provider::Service::Systemd
    default['kibana']['service']['source'] = 'systemd.service.erb'
    default['kibana']['service']['template_file'] = '/usr/lib/systemd/system/kibana.service'
  end
when 'ubuntu'
  if node['platform_version'] < '16.04'
    default['kibana']['service']['provider'] = Chef::Provider::Service::Upstart
    default['kibana']['service']['source'] = 'upstart.conf.erb'
    default['kibana']['service']['template_file'] = '/etc/init/kibana.conf'
    default['kibana']['service']['upstart'] = true
  else
    default['kibana']['service']['provider'] = Chef::Provider::Service::Systemd
    default['kibana']['service']['source'] = 'systemd.service.erb'
    default['kibana']['service']['template_file'] = '/lib/systemd/system/kibana.service'
  end
end
```

It is not established before that case block, and the case block has no else statement, so outside of those two situations (centos, aws, or ubuntu) it's not going to work